# How to show $f\left(r\left(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta\right)\right) = \sin (\theta)$ is continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

If we define $f(0)= 0$ I know is not continuous in $0$ since you can approximate to zero from the imaginary line and then you have the limit is $1$ or $-1$.

Is correct just approximate from the director line, or fixing the modulus and then using that sine is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is "sen" of theta?

Comment: sin in spanish.

Comment: Is the goal to prove it's continuous everywhere except 0?

Comment: Yes, that my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your function is *not* defined at $0$; for $z\ne0$,
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i|z|}
$$

Comment: I still don't see how to proceed.

Comment: @HectorGurle Sums, products and quotients (where defined) of continuous functions are continuous.